# problem in deserialization of passport for two login system

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I have built login system using passportjs for teacher and student .But on deserialise the object type not matching teacher and student it goes to default.i'm separating the user is because its db model is different, and the passport strategies is different too. In this i had saved password in hash .
using bcrypt by which password will be retrieve . on teacher login, I expect to go on teacher in deserialise and on student login I expect to go on student on deserialising. But it goes to default always.To have two different strategies(student and teacher here) , We make two local strategies and serialize and deserialize them accordingly.

I dont uderstand how deserialize work in this and do i have to assign any obj type in my database???

```js
app.get("/register", function(req, res){
    res.render("reg")
})

app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    var type = req.body.type
    if(type=="student"){
    var newUser = new Student({
        username: req.body.username,
        gender: req.body.gender,
        rollnumber: req.body.rollnumber,
        dob: req.body.dob,
        email: req.body.email,
        type: req.body.type,
        password: req.body.password
    })

    req.checkBody('username','UserName is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('rollnumber','Roll Number is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email Invalid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password','Password is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password1','Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors){
        res.render('Sregister', {errors: errors});
    }else{
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,  salt){
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash){
            if(!err){
                newUser.password = hash;
            }
            newUser.save(function(err){
                if(!err){
                    console.log("success in reg");
                    res.redirect("/student/login")
                }
            })
        })
    })
    }}
    else if(type=="teacher"){
        var newUser = new Teacher({
        username: req.body.username,
        gender: req.body.gender,
        rollnumber: req.body.rollnumber,
        dob: req.body.dob,
        email: req.body.email,
        type: req.body.type,
        password: req.body.password
    })

    req.checkBody('username','UserName is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('rollnumber','Roll Number is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email Invalid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password','Password is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password1','Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors){
        res.render('Sregister', {errors: errors});
    }else{

             bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,  salt){
                 bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash){
                    if(!err){
                         newUser.password = hash;
                  }
                        newUser.save(function(err){
                     if(!err){
                         console.log("success in reg");
                         res.redirect("/teacher/login")
                }
            })
        })
    })
    }}
})

//strategies

passport.use('student', new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done){
    var query = {username: username};
    Student.findOne(query, function(err, student){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!student){
            return done(null, false);
        }
        bcrypt.compare(password,student.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(isMatch)
                return done(null, student);
            else
                return done(null,false);
        })
    })
}))

passport.use('teacher', new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done){
    var query = {username: username};
    Teacher.findOne(query, function(err, teacher){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!teacher){
            console.log("no teach")
            return done(null, false);
        }
        bcrypt.compare(password,teacher.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(isMatch)
                return done(null, teacher);
            else
                return done(null,false);
        })
    })
}))

//serialize deserizlize

passport.serializeUser(function (entity, done) {
    done(null, { id: entity.id, type: entity.type });
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
    switch (obj.type) {
        case 'student':
            Student.findById(obj.id)
                .then(user => {
                    if (user) {
                        done(null, user);
                    }
                    else {
                        done(new Error('user id not found:' + obj.id, null));
                    }
                });
            break;
        case 'teacher':
            Teacher.findById(obj.id)
                .then(device => {
                    if (device) {
                        done(null, device);
                    } else {
                        done(new Error('device id not found:' + obj.id, null));
                    }
                });
            break;
        default:
            done(new Error('no entity type:', obj.type), null);
            break;
    }
});
//login routes

app.get("/student/login", function(req, res){
    res.render("slogin")
})

app.get("/teacher/login", function(req, res){
    res.render("tlogin")
})

app.post('/student/login', 
  passport.authenticate('student', { successRedirect: '/student/home', failureRedirect: '/student/login' }));

app.post('/teacher/login', 
  passport.authenticate('teacher', { successRedirect: '/teacher/home', failureRedirect: '/teacher/login' }));


app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home");  
})

app.get("/student/home", function(req, res){
  res.send("hi student")
})

app.get("/teacher/home", function(req, res){
  res.send("hi teacher")  
})
```